# Unable to login/register from My account page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, bluehost

I am trying to setup this theme. Every thing was working fine but when i moved my site to this new host at BLUEHOST.

Suddenly my i am not able to login using word press social login.

So did some research that Varnish caching may be the issue. But this social login is not the issue now.

**Main Problem**
Now i am not able to login using my account page. When a user registers he is registered in the backend but not automatically logged in.

So what is the issue
please help

Comment: There is a more specific site for [wordpress questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) with the same stackoverflow format, but in any case, if you think the problem is related to bluehost, you can [chat with them directly](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/chatlite) about it.

Comment: @Armfoot thanks for the suggestion but i wordpress.stackexchange doesn't help out with woocommerce related problems.And I did chat with them about that wordpress social login plugin but they were unable to do help out, They just told shold they disable varnish

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your varnish settings against the woocommerce documentation?
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-caching-plugins/

```
if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account|checkout|addons)") {
 return (pass);
}
if ( req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) {
  return (pass);
 }
```

Also mentioned in the article a possible issue with cookies and varnish

```
Add this to vcl_recv above "if (req.http.cookie) {":

# Unset Cookies except for WordPress admin and WooCommerce pages 
if (!(req.url ~ "(wp-login|wp-admin|cart|my-account/*|checkout|addons|logout|lost-password|product/*)")) { 
unset req.http.cookie; 
} 
# Pass through the WooCommerce dynamic pages 
if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account/*|checkout|addons|logout|lost-password|product/*)") { 
return (pass); 
} 
# Pass through the WooCommerce add to cart 
if (req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) { 
return (pass); 
} 
# Block access to php admin pages via website 
if (req.url ~ "^/phpmyadmin/.*$" || req.url ~ "^/phppgadmin/.*$" || req.url ~ "^/server-status.*$") { 
error 403 "For security reasons, this URL is only accesible using localhost (127.0.0.1) as the hostname"; 
} 
#

Add this to vcl_fetch:

# Unset Cookies except for WordPress admin and WooCommerce pages 
if ( (!(req.url ~ "(wp-(login|admin)|login|cart|my-account/*|checkout|addons|logout|lost-password|product/*)")) || (req.request == "GET") ) { 
unset beresp.http.set-cookie; 
} 
#
```

Comment: nice reference mbanard, it's better if you copy&paste that Varnish configuration to the answer... Just in case the page ceases to exist. Inside they also mention: [how cookies may be affecting your varnish coding](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/varnish-configuration-not-working-in-woocommerce).

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion Armfoot, I just updated my answer.

Comment: @mbarbard thanks for the help.  But BLUEHOST doesn't give option to configure varnish. I have change my webhost.. But your solution will definitly come handy to lot of people . thank you